# Run python command with different variables?

Tags: python

I want to execute python script with different variables. I have to batch images files from folder, but i just want to execute from the script with different variables. Like

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18. 19, 20]

!python autozoom.py --in ./images/1.jpg --out ./videos/1.mp4
!python autozoom.py --in ./images/2.jpg --out ./videos/2.mp4
!python autozoom.py --in ./images/3.jpg --out ./videos/3.mp4
!python autozoom.py --in ./images/4.jpg --out ./videos/4.mp4
```

etc until 20

i'm sorry, i'm absolute beginner about python language.. Any answers or advices i will very apreciated! :) Thank you

Comment: Look into [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.system) (e.g. `for i in range(1, 21): os.system(f"!python autozoom.py --in ./images/{i}.jpg --out ./videos/{i}.mp4")`)

Comment: @rassar, ...that's not a good habit to be in -- this is safe right now as long as the only value you substitute is an integer; but the moment you're handling user-defined filenames, using `os.system()` with string substitution becomes extremely unsafe.

Comment: @Faiz, ...typically, the best approach is to have your script define a function that can be called with different variables, so you import the function from the script and then call it as many times as you need in your loop. (If you have a `__main__` that parses command line arguments like `--in` and `--out`, best-practice code will then use that code to call the function that does the work, so other Python code can just import that function directly and invoke it *without* needing to generate anything that looks like a command-line argument list).

Comment: So, the *best* way to solve your problem requires changing, or at least knowing, what's in `autozoom.py`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you any other docs or guides link for me ? Thank you!, I was confused about creating function in python.

Comment: @rassar thank youu rassar!

Comment: Is `autozoom.py` your own code? If not, where did it come from? If so, could we see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about how `autozoom.py` would best be written to support this kind of use case, *without* needing to start a new Python interpreter 20 different times. In an *ideal* world, it might look something like the following:

```
import argparse

def convert(infile, outfile):
    pass # do the magic here

def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser
    ap.add_argument('--in', dest='infile', type=argparse.FileType('rb'))
    ap.add_argument('--out', dest='outfile', type=argparse.FileType('wb'))
    args = ap.parse_args()
    convert(args.infile, args.outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

...where the command-line parsing code calls a function that does the *real* work, but that function can also be called directly.

If that's the case, your code to use the `convert` function might look like:

```
import autozoom

for i in range(1, 21):
    with open(f'images/{i}.jpg', 'rb') as input_file, \
         open(f'videos/{i}.mp4', 'wb') as output_file:
        autozoom.convert(input_file, output_file)
```